# Voltage regulators in SPICE software

Tags: voltage-regulator, software, spice, ltspice

I am having trouble figuring out how to add voltage regulators to my circuit for SPICE simulation. The regulator is a 78L10AC voltage regulator, 10V, 5% output tolerance, LP package. I have most of my circuit figured out (I think), but am unsure as to how to write the statement for the voltage regulator.

If anyone could help me out a bit that would be great. Also looking for any recommended reference for SPICE software. (I have never used this before). We have a bunch listed that we can use, just want to see if anyone has a highly recommended, preferred document that they use as reference.

I will most likely be using LT Spice or PSpice. (any recommendations there?)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to write the netlist, then it will be something like:

`XU1 N001 0 N001 N002 +10V LT1761-SD`

The above is an adjustable regulator with 5 pins (IN, OUT, GND, ADJ and SHDN)

It's a subcircuit, so it's declared with an X. Also, since complex subcircuits are usually written in a separate file, you need to make sure the subcircuit file is included in the netlist with a declaration like:

`.lib LT1761.lib`

Alternatively you can add the subcircuit code directly into the netlist.
I would recommend LTSpice, it's an excellent, easy/quick to use and powerful free SPICE.